# Calling Javascript from dynamic form button in yii2

Tags: yii2

In Yii2 Dynamic form, I have add-item and remove-item button to add a new row or remove a particular row. What I want is to call a javascript function on click of the remove item button.

Dynamic Form Code -

```
<?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]productname")->widget(Select2::classname(), [
'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Productbatch::find()->orderBy('productname')->all(),'productname','productname'),
'language' => 'en',
'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Product', 'onchange' => 'getHsndetails($(this))'],
'pluginOptions' => [
    'allowClear' => true
],
])->label(false);
?>

<?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]batchno")->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
'options' => ['onload' => 'getProdValues($(this))','onchange' => 'getItemID($(this))'],
'pluginOptions'=>[
    'depends'=> [Html::getInputID($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]productname")],
    'placeholder'=>'Batch',
    'url'=>Url::to(['/invoice/bills/subcat'])
]
])->label(false); ?>

<?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]expdate")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'placeholder' => 'ExpDate','readOnly'=>true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]mrp")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'class' => 'mrp','placeholder' => 'MRP']) ?>

<?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]rate")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'class' => 'rate','placeholder' => 'Rate']) ?>

<?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]qty")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'class' => 'qty','placeholder' => 'Qty']) ?>

<?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]free")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'class' => 'free','placeholder' => 'Free']) ?>


<?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]discount")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'class' => 'disc','placeholder' => 'Discount']) ?>


<div class="pull-right">
    <button type="button" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
    <button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
</div>
```

Javascript function

```
<?php
/* start getting the total amount */
$this->registerJs('
    function getSum() {
        var retailPrice = 0;
        var stockistPrice = 0;
        var sum = 0;
        var totalDiscount = 0;
        var totalMrp = 0;
        var totalCst = 0;
        var totalWbst = 0;
        var totalCstonamount = 0;
        var totalWbstonamount = 0;
        var totalCstonmrp = 0;
        var totalWbstonmrp = 0;
        var totalTaxonmrp = 0;
        var totalTaxonamount = 0;
        var totalAmountonmrp = 0;
        var totalAmountonrate = 0;
        var totalBillamountonmrp = 0;
        var totalBillamountonrate = 0;
        var igstAmount = 0;
        var cgstAmount = 0;
        var sgstAmount = 0;

        var cstperValue = $(".cstPercent").val();
        var wbstperValue = $(".wbstPercent").val();
        var selectedValue = $("input[name=taxon]:checked").val();
        //alert(selectedValue);

        var items = $(".item");

        items.each(function (index, elem) {
        var qtyValue = $(elem).find(".qty").val();
        var rateValue = $(elem).find(".rate").val();
        var discValue = $(elem).find(".disc").val();
        var mrpValue = $(elem).find(".mrp").val();
        var freeValue = $(elem).find(".free").val();
        var igstPercent = $(elem).find(".igstrate").val();
        var cgstPercent = $(elem).find(".cgstrate").val();
        var sgstPercent = $(elem).find(".sgstrate").val();



        cgstAmount = (parseFloat(cgstAmount) + ((parseFloat(qtyValue)*parseFloat(rateValue) - (parseFloat(qtyValue)*parseFloat(rateValue)*parseFloat(discValue))/100)*parseFloat(cgstPercent))/100).toFixed(2);

        sgstAmount = (parseFloat(sgstAmount) + ((parseFloat(qtyValue)*parseFloat(rateValue) - (parseFloat(qtyValue)*parseFloat(rateValue)*parseFloat(discValue))/100)*parseFloat(sgstPercent))/100).toFixed(2);

        igstAmount = (parseFloat(igstAmount) + ((parseFloat(qtyValue)*parseFloat(rateValue) - (parseFloat(qtyValue)*parseFloat(rateValue)*parseFloat(discValue))/100)*parseFloat(igstPercent))/100).toFixed(2);

        stockistPrice = (parseFloat(stockistPrice) + (parseFloat(rateValue)*parseFloat(qtyValue) - (parseFloat(rateValue)*parseFloat(qtyValue)*parseFloat(discValue))/100)).toFixed(2);

        sum = Math.round(parseFloat(stockistPrice) + parseFloat(cgstAmount) + parseFloat(sgstAmount) + parseFloat(igstAmount));

    });

   if(isNaN(sum) || sum.length == 0) {
       sum = 0;
   }
   if(isNaN(cgstAmount) || cgstAmount.length == 0) {
       cgstAmount = 0;
   }
   if(isNaN(sgstAmount) || sgstAmount.length == 0) {
       sgstAmount = 0;
   }
   if(isNaN(igstAmount) || igstAmount.length == 0) {
       igstAmount = 0;
   }
   if(isNaN(stockistPrice) || stockistPrice.length == 0) {
       stockistPrice = 0;
   }


   $(".sum").val(sum);
   $(".cgstAmount").val(cgstAmount);
   $(".sgstAmount").val(sgstAmount);
   $(".igstAmount").val(igstAmount);
   $(".totalAmount").val(stockistPrice);

   $(".billAmount").val(sum);
   $(".overdueAmount").val(sum);


    }


    $(".container-items").on("change", function() {
        getSum();
    });
    $(".remove-item").on("click", function() {
        getSum();
        alert("This Onclick is working");
    });

');
/*end getting the total amount */
?>
```

On Change of the items, the javascript is being called and I'm getting the value. But on Click of the remove-item button, the javascript is not getting called. Please let me know what to do to call the javascript `onclick` of the `remove-item` button.

There's no error in the console.

Comment: have you tried  commenting the getSum() inside your on click function ? .. could be you have error in the getSum() function

Comment: do select the answer if it helped you out

Answer (score 0):

If the adding and removing the fields are the only functions that are only manipulating the form then you can use the new [**`MutationObserver`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to track if any new elements were added or removed from the target container.

This new DOM Api is available in `Firefox` and `Webkit` nightly builds, as well as `Chrome` 18.

> The key advantage to this new specification over the deprecated DOM
>   Mutation Events spec is one of efficiency. If you are observing a node
>   for changes, your callback will not be fired until the DOM has
>   finished changing. When the callback is triggered, it is supplied a
>   list of the changes to the DOM, which you can then loop through and
>   choose to react to.
>
> This also means that any code you write will need to process the
>   observer results in order to react to the changes you are looking for.

Consider the following example which adds and removes divs inside a container div using the `add` and `remove` buttons, and i use `MutationObserver` to look for the changes in the target element `#container` and update the div count inside the `callback` function after checking the the Mutation Event is for the `ChildList` which is triggered when you add or remove the child elements from the target container.

```js
function startObserver() {
  // select the target node
  var target = document.querySelector('#container');
  
  // create an observer instance
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
        $('.counter').html($("#container>div").length + ' div(s) total');
      }
    });
  });

  // configuration of the observer:
  var config = {
    childList: true,
  }

  // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
  observer.observe(target, config);
}

jQuery(function($) {
  $("#add-more").on("click", function() {
    $("#container").append("<div>some thing " + Math.random() + "</div>")
  })

  $("#remove").on("click", function() {
    $("#container>div:eq(0)").remove()
  });

  startObserver();
});
```

```css
.counter {
  float: right;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: red;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section"><button id="add-more">add more</button>
  <button id="remove">Remove</button>
  <div class="counter">0 div(s) total</div>
  <div id='container'>

  </div>
```

What you need to do is to wrap the form inside a div and provide it an `id` say `container` and add the call to the function `getSum()` inside the `callback` function you can copy the below code.

```
$this->registerJs("// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#container');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
       if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
           getSum();
       }
    });
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { childList: true};

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);     
", yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

*NOTE: Remove any other calls to the `getSum()` function if you have added it to any other event like below*

```
 $(".remove-item").on("click", function() {
        getSum();
        alert("This Onclick is working");
    });
```

Hope this helps you sort the problem.