# javascript modify contents of dynamically loaded pop-up element

Tags: javascript

**Note 1**: I do not own the website to which I'm trying to apply this script on, so I can't access the source code for manual edit.

**Note 2**: I need PURE javascript (NOT jquery). I will use the script inside tampermonkey for Firefox v56, and I don't want to load any external *.js libraries. I need PURE JS code.

Ok, so here it goes...

The site in question, inside its `body` has a button, like this:

```
<button class="bad_button js-only">reply</button>
```

Among other page elements, there is one `div` element that looks like this:

```
<div class="returnprofile js-only" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Once I press the above button:
- page dynamically build/create a `script` element and insert it inside a page `head`
- then fill-in that 'hidden' `div` element with content by pulling information from some database
- then makes the above mantioned `div` element visible by changing it `style` from `display: none` to `display: block`
- and finally I'm presented with a pop-up that show information like this:

```
<div class="returnprofile js-only" style="display: block;">
    <aside class="profile-flap js-captcha">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h1>nick name:</h1>
                <p>fR3r0X</p>
            </li>

            <li class="skill">
                <h1>
                    <span class="most_used">Cyclone</span>
                </h1>
                <p class="attack_skill">
                    Ancestral Warchief
                </p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
</div>
```

Now, what I have described doesn't happen instantly. It takes time. And its always a random time. I observed whats happening while watching in firebug, and from what I can tell it uses some google recaptcha scripts, and also pull all the information from some database to fill it into that pop-up.

**What I want?**:
 I want to put a button 'somewhere' inside that `div` pop-up, so once I click on it, I can copy the innerText of some of the elements, eg. Skill Name'. I don't need you to help me with inserting a button. I'll figure that out.

**What is the problem?**:
 I can't 'lock' (hook) any of the elements inside that `div` pop-up, because its contents load dynamically once my script is already done its work, and the dynamic script that original page create once I click the button is 'loaded' last.

so I can't 'find' the element and put it into variable by using `document.getElementsByClassName` or `document.getElementsByTagName` or `document.querySelector` etc.

I've already searched for solution here and over google and I can't find the code examples that I can use for this. I've tried with making a function with timeout, just to see if I can 'hook' one of the elements which are part of that div pop-up once it shows up.

I tried just for testing something like this:

```
setTimeout( function () {
    var skill = document.querySelector('.attack_skill');
    skill.style.background = "yellow";
}, 3000);
```

And...sometimes that works and sometimes it doesn't. And all depends on the amount of time I selected my function to 'wait'. So if the website in question takes more time to fill the contet of that `div` pop-up, and my function try to fire-up before that, nothing will happen. I can 'fix' that by incresing a timeout value, but thats not a solution. If I put it to be...lets say 20 sec waiting before my function starts, and website show div pop-up in 3 sec, that means I would be looking at my monitor screen, waiting 17 sec for script to fire-up.
So I need a way to access (and change) elements of that `div` pop-up as soon as it is presented. If that pop-up needs 20 sec to show up, so be it, but once it does show up, I want my own javascript code to be executed instantly (without any timeouts or lags).

I've looked around...and since I'm a newb, maybe I got it all wrong, but 'I think" I need some 'event listeners'. I don't know how to use them. I saw they are being used (fired up) as a 'click' events. But I need (if such thing exist) an event that will start my code once certain element show-up. Maybe in my case it could be attached to that moment when a hidden div change its state from `display:none` to `display:block` . I don't know, thats how I was 'brainstorming' how to get around it, even if I have no clue how I would code such thing. :(

I hope, I've managed to explain whats the problem and what I need.

If someone decide to attach a code example, he can 'just add' a button inside some of the elements of that div pop-up, eg. inside `<p class="attack_skill">` or just change the background or something like that. Main goal is to show me how to 'hook' to that element (or any elmement that is part of div pop-up) which 'creates itself dynamically.

Thanks in advance to everyone who decided to read my 'novel' and try to help me!

Comment: What you need to do, is be notified once the contents of the div changes. One used to use the `DOMSubtreeModified` event, but this has been deprecated and you now use the `MutationObserver` api. Here's a link to the MDN page that also shows an example of use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver enjoy!

Comment: enhzflep, thx for your reply, I'll check it out.

Comment: an answer here could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50004550/calling-javascript-from-dynamic-form-button-in-yii2/50010891#50010891

Comment: Muhammad Omer Aslam, thanks! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) (and [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)), instead of `setTimeout`, to [poll](https://www.quora.com/What-does-polling-mean-in-computer-science) for your desired condition:

```
var x;

// run some code every 1000ms to check for the presence of an element    
x = setInterval(function() {
  const el = document.querySelector('blahblahblah');

  if (el !== null) {
    // my element is on the page; no need to poll any more
    clearInterval(x);
    // do some things here
    el.style.background = 'yellow';
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Dan O, thx for your code. If I understood, it still uses some 'time' values (eve if its 1 sec). If the pop-up show up in 20 sec, that means script will be checking 20x until it finds what it is searching for until execute desired action. Correct?

Comment: correct - this code checks 1x a second.  if it takes 20 seconds for the element to appear, this code will run 19x and report that your element is not present in the DOM, then run once more, discover the element, and prevent itself from running any more in the future.

Comment: Dan O, I've tested your code and it does perfectly what I needed. I modified the elements I wanted, managed to put the button to copy the innerHTML content of some of the elements. Everything works! Thanks!  Just one more extra question so that newb like me can understand everything completely: Your script is watching (looking) for 'non existing element' until it show up, right? It doesn't wait for pop-up holder div to change it state from display:none to display:block, but instead waits for specific element which will be part of that pop-up div once it shows up? Correct? Again, thanks!

Comment: right.  the code I pasted is, once a second, asking your document a question:  "hey, does this element exist anywhere in your element tree?"  the answer to that question is "yes" or "no", regardless of what CSS rules are applied.  CSS has no effect on the contents of the DOM; it only changes how those contents are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), this code will track any changes to `.returnprofile` element and fires a callback in response. (changes are simulated using a timeout here):

```js
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
var targetNode = document.querySelector('.returnprofile');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
var config = { childList: true, characterData: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
var callback = function(mutationsList) {
    targetNode.style.backgroundColor = 'tomato';

   // Uncomment the next line if you want to run this callback only once, otherwise it will run anytime targetNode is mutated.
   //observer.disconnect();
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

setTimeout(function() {
 targetNode.innerHTML = "I'm changed";
}, 3000);
```

```html
<div class="returnprofile js-only">Not Changed</div>
```

Comment: Amr Noman, thanks for your code. I'll test that one as well and see if it works at the website I'm trying to use a javascript code on.

Comment: You're welcome, please note that the callback will run anytime your element is changed, if you only want it to run once you'll need to disconnect the observer inside your callback...I edited the code with a comment showing that.

Comment: Amr Noman, thanks again for trying to help me. I've tried your code, and I coudn't manage to make it work for my case. The pop-up holder div which is hidden and empty at the zero stage, gets populated dinamicly and start being visible. I needed a way to, once it become visible, access elements that it holds in that moment and modify them. I coudn't managed that with your script or maybe since I'm newbie I did something wrong while trying to implement your solution. Anyway, thanks for your help and for all comments you put with every line of code you've shared.